# Gradle build generates an apk with android:testOnly=true and I don't understand why

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, google-play

The APK generated by Gradle produces an INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY error when installed. Inside the androidManifest, I have `android:testOnly="true"`. There is no problem when I install the apk with the `adb -t` option.

The issue is that the application cannot be installed from the Play Store. I have set `android:testOnly="false"` in my app/src/main AndroidManifest.xml and added `android.injected.testOnly=false` in gradle.properties at the top level, but unfortunately, it has not resolved the problem.

I am using Gradle 7.5.1

Comment: How are you getting the APK that you are submitting to the Play Store? `FLAG_TEST_ONLY` is added automatically for builds created by running the app from the IDE, or at least [it was six years ago](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/10/31/android-studio-3p0-flag-test-only.html).

Comment: I built my APK with gradle. I downloaded the APK from the Play Store and checked that testOnly=true.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found is to rewrite AndroidManistest.xml file with `android:testOnly="false"`.

To do that, I added the following code to /android/app/build.gradle

```
android {
....
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
  if(variant.name.contains("Release")) {
      println("variant.name: " + variant.name);
      variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.processManifest.doLast {
            String manifestPath = "${buildDir}/intermediates/merged_manifests/${variant.name}/AndroidManifest.xml"
            def manifestContent = file(manifestPath).getText('UTF-8')
            manifestContent = manifestContent.replaceAll("android:testOnly=\"true\"", "android:testOnly=\"false\"")
            file(manifestPath).write(manifestContent, 'UTF-8')
        }
      }
  }

}
```

I have no idea why the problem occurs.